# Downloading data (JSON) not working: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am making a 'My weather app', in which I'm practicing with downloading data from the web. But I get a error when testing with a static URL, and I don't know why.

Part of my Weather Model:

```
init(location: String, temp: Double, icon: String) {
        self._location = location
        self._temp = temp
        self._icon = icon

        url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=52.379189&lon=4.899431&APPID=28c704926d4f9131886a0bce5d2425d9"
    }

    func downloadWeatherDetails(completed: DownloadComplete) {
        let weatherUrl = NSURL(string: url)!
        Alamofire.request(.GET, weatherUrl).responseJSON { response in
            let result = response.result
            print(result.value.debugDescription)
        }
    }
```

Part of my ViewController:

```
var weather: Weather!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        weather.downloadWeatherDetails() { () -> () in
            //This will be called after download is done
       }
    }
```

My 'Constants' file:

```
typealias DownloadComplete = () -> ()
```

The URL is working when I'm testing it in the browser, so that's not the point. I don't know what is going wrong. Could anyone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Where is `var weather` set? Without assigning a value somewhere the variable is `nil`

Comment: It's set in the ViewController: var weather: Weather! Is that the wrong way?

Comment: My first guess is you're a victim of App Transport Security. Have you put an exception in your info.plist? If you add in an error component to the Alamofire call, you should be able to add a breakpoint and inspect it -- look for "The resource could not be loaded because the App Transport Security policy requires the use of a secure connection."

Comment: `var weather: Weather!` is a declaration of a variable as implicit unwrapped optional. You need to assign a value which is an instance of the class.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! Yes, I did the 'App transport security' thing, but it still isn't working. And the code is also not working with other URLs, so that's not the problem I think? And I made 'var weather: Weather!', only to call the function in the Model 'Weather'. So I don't have a value to assign to. Is there another possible problem I'm not seeing?

Comment: I fixed it with: var weather = Weather() and I did a double check on some variables! Thanks a lot for helping:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an instance of the Weather class.

```
var weather = Weather()
```